# Auto generate comment when overriding an interface function?

Tags: java, interface

I want sth like this

```
public interface A {
    void doSth(int a); // a in ms 
}
```

when I override `doSth`, the comment "a in ms" also appear in the code.

```
A a = new A() {
    @Override
    public void doSth(int a) { // a in ms
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: why not just say: void doSth(int timeInMS); ?

Comment: Just put the comment on the method of the interface (`/**....*/` style), it will appear in your IDE when you hover over the overriding method.

Comment: this interface is in the aar library, so when i use it, the params get renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `JavaDoc`, more clear and more readable

```
public interface A {
    /**
     * Write your method java doc
     * @param a The int must be in milliseconds
     */
    void doSth(int a);
}
```

I also suggest you to use clear parameters names: for example you can replace `int a` with `int milliseconds`

Comment: this interface is in the aar library, so when i use it, the params get renamed

Comment: i write the java doc but the comments still not appear in the overide.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, there is an option called *Auto generate comments*, that will generate comment stubs when you create a new class or interface.

You will have to write the javadoc comment in the interface yourself, like this:

```
public interface IThing {

    /**
     * This method does something with milliseconds
     * @param millis the milliseconds for the calculation
     */
    void doSomething(int millis);
}
```

Then, when you create a class that implements the interface, overridden methods get a reference in their javadoc comments that makes them show the comment of the method in the interface:

```
public class Thing implements IThing {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see mypackage.IThing#doSomething(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void doSomething(int millis) {
        System.out.println("The calculation got the value of "
                + millis + " milliseconds as parameter");
    }

}
```

The syntax looks like `javadoc-tag {package}.{interface}#{method(parameter type}`,
here: `@see mypackage.IThing#doSomething(int)`

I don't know if you are using eclipse, but it seems like you can use those references in other IDEs as well (it is a javadoc feature, I think).
Try it, maybe it is (nearly) what you want…

> Alternatively, you may want to have a look at [{@inheritDoc}](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc) .

Comment: I use android studio and it seems not having that option.

Comment: Then you might have to put the non-javadoc inheritance to the methods of the subclasses yourself. I don't have Android Studio at the moment and cannot view the options. Does the javadoc inheritance work if you write it manually?

Comment: My interface is used by other devs, so i want my comments somehow appear when they overide the function.

Comment: If you are writing the interface and commenting it, then the other developers have to use one of my suggestions… If you write a proper javadoc comment, it will appear when they override the methods *and apply some kind of javadoc inheritance*. Just tell them how it can be done.